# Html theme switcher

Tags: javascript, html, css, themes

I want to to implement a theme switcher. I followed this [tutorial](https://dev.to/ananyaneogi/create-a-dark-light-mode-switch-with-css-variables-34l8) but it's not working. When I click on the button, nothing changes. You can find the js at the bottom (theme switcher);the html is in the "menu";the css is at the bottom.

I think the problem is inside the js but can't understand what it is

```js
/*<!-------Script du menu------->*/

const list = document.querySelectorAll('.list');
function activeLink(){
  list.forEach((item) =>
  item.classList.remove('active'));
  this.classList.add('active');
}
list.forEach((item) =>  
item.addEventListener('click', activeLink));

window.onmousedown = e => {
    const track = document.getElementById("image-track");

    track.dataset.mouseDownAt = e.clientX;
}

window.onmouseup = () => {
    const track = document.getElementById("image-track");

    track.dataset.mouseDownAt = "0";
    track.dataset.prevPercentage = track.dataset.percentage;
}

window.onmousemove = e => {
    const track = document.getElementById("image-track");
    const tips = document.getElementById("tips");
    if(track.dataset.mouseDownAt == "0") return;
    
    const mouseDelta = parseFloat(track.dataset.mouseDownAt) - e.clientX, maxDelta = window.innerWidth / 2;

    const percentage = (mouseDelta / maxDelta) * -100, nextPercentage = Math.max(Math.min(parseFloat(track.dataset.prevPercentage) + percentage, 0), -100);
    
    track.dataset.percentage = nextPercentage;
    
    track.animate({
        transform: `translate(${nextPercentage}%, -50%)`
    }, { duration: 1200, fill: "forwards" });

    tips.animate({
        transform: `translate(${nextPercentage * 2}%, -50%)`
    }, { duration: 1200, fill: "forwards" });

    for(const image of track.getElementsByClassName("image")) {
        image.animate({
            objectPosition: `${100 + nextPercentage}% center`
        }, { duration: 1200, fill: "forwards" });
    }
}


/*fonction pour v�rifier l'age*/
function verifAge() {
    var age = document.getElementById('age').value;
if (age>130) {
    alert("Personne n'a vecu aussi longtemps ! Age entre : "+ age+"ans");
} else if (age<18) {
    alert("Vous devez etre majeur pour realiser ce questionnaire ! Age entr� : "+ age+"ans");
} else {
    alert("Vous avez l'age requis !");
}

/*fonction pour v�rifier l'age*/
function verifnumber() {
    var age = document.getElementById('rep1').value;
if (age>10) {
    alert("Vous ne pouvez pas alle au dela de 10");
} else if (age<0) {
    alert("Vous ne pouvez pas alle en dessous de 0");
}
}
}

/*fonction pour afficher un message*/
function messInfo(ntext) {
var x = document.getElementById('info');
x.innerHTML = ntext;
x.className = "show";
setTimeout(function(){ x.className = x.className.replace("show", ""); }, 3000);
}

/*verification question 4*/
if (document.getElementById("quest4").checked === true) {
var preference = "Led Zeppelin";
}

/*verification question 5*/
if (document.getElementById("quest5").checked === true) {
var preference = "Au grunge";
}

/*theme switcher*/
const toggleSwitch = document.querySelector('.theme-switch input[type="checkbox"]');
const currentTheme = localStorage.getItem('theme');

if (currentTheme) {
    document.documentElement.setAttribute('data-theme', currentTheme);
  
    if (currentTheme === 'dark') {
        toggleSwitch.checked = true;
    }
}

function switchTheme(e) {
    if (e.target.checked) {
        document.documentElement.setAttribute('data-theme', 'dark');
        localStorage.setItem('theme', 'dark');
    }
    else {        document.documentElement.setAttribute('data-theme', 'light');
          localStorage.setItem('theme', 'light');
    }    
}

toggleSwitch.addEventListener('change', switchTheme, false);
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Mooli&display=swap');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Oswald:wght@500&display=swap');
/* -------Variables------- */

:root {
    --navButtonSize: 25%;
    --text: #020401;
    --background: #f1f8ef;
    --primary: #94d283;
    --secondary: #d5edce;
    --accent: #58b040;
}

[data-theme="theme-dark"] {
    --navButtonSize: 25%;
    --text: #f1f8ef;
    --background: #020401;
    --primary: #94d283;
    --secondary: #0d1a09;
    --accent: #b6e0aa;
}

/* -------Cacher la barre de scroll------- */

body 
{
  -ms-overflow-style: none; /* Pour Internet Explorer, Edge */
  scrollbar-width: none; /* Pour Firefox */
  overflow-y: scroll; 
}

body::-webkit-scrollbar 
{
  display: none; /* Pour Chrome, Safari, and Opera */
}

/* -------Fond/Police------- */

body 
{
    font-family: 'Mooli', sans-serif;
    background: var(--background);
}

/* ----------------------------Menu---------------------------- */

/* -------Barre du menu------- */

nav
{
    position: fixed;
    margin: 0px auto 0;
    margin-left: 0px;
    top: 5px;
    width: 98.5%;
    height: 50px;
    background: var(--secondary);
    border-radius: 8px;
    font-size: 0;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 3px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.1);
}

/* -------Le texte des boutons du menu------- */

nav a
{
    font-size: 30px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: var(--text);
    font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
    text-decoration: none;
    line-height: 50px;
    width: 80px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
}

/* -------Barre de survole de bouton------- */

nav .animation
{
    position: absolute;
    height: 10%;
    bottom: 0;
    z-index: 0;
    background: var(--primary);
    border-radius: 8px;
    transition: all .5s ease 0s;
    opacity: 0;
}

/* -------Indicateur de la page------- */

.indicator
{
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 0;
    background: var(--primary);
    border-radius: 8px;
    transition: all .5s ease 0s;
}

/* -------Cache le surplus (le texte qui monte) derrière le menu------- */

.cache
{
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 55px;
    background: var(--background);
    z-index: 0;
}

/* -------Les enfants de la barre de survole, de l'indicateur et des boutons du menu------- */

nav a:nth-child(1)
{
    width: var(--navButtonSize);
}
nav a:nth-child(1):hover~.animation
{
    width: var(--navButtonSize);
    left: 0%;
    opacity: 1;
}
nav a:nth-child(1).active~.indicator
{
    width: var(--navButtonSize);
    left: 0%;
}
nav a:nth-child(1).active:hover~.animation
{
    opacity: 0;
}

nav a:nth-child(2)
{
    width: var(--navButtonSize);
}
nav a:nth-child(2):hover~.animation
{
    width: var(--navButtonSize);
    left: 25%;
    opacity: 1;
}
nav a:nth-child(2).active~.indicator
{
    width: var(--navButtonSize);
    left: 25%;
}
nav a:nth-child(2).active:hover~.animation
{
    opacity: 0;
}

nav a:nth-child(3)
{
    width: var(--navButtonSize);
}
nav a:nth-child(3):hover~.animation
{
    width: var(--navButtonSize);
    left: 50%;
    opacity: 1;
}
nav a:nth-child(3).active~.indicator
{
    width: var(--navButtonSize);
    left: 50%;
}
nav a:nth-child(3).active:hover~.animation
{
    opacity: 0;
}

nav a:nth-child(4)
{
    width: var(--navButtonSize);
}
nav a:nth-child(4):hover~.animation
{
    width: var(--navButtonSize);
    left: 75%;
    opacity: 1;
}
nav a:nth-child(4).active~.indicator
{
    width: var(--navButtonSize);
    left: 75%;
}
nav a:nth-child(4).active:hover~.animation
{
    opacity: 0;
}

nav a:nth-child(5)
{
    width: var(--navButtonSize);
}
nav a:nth-child(5):hover~.animation
{
    width: var(--navButtonSize);
    left: 100%;
    opacity: 1;
}
nav a:nth-child(5).active~.indicator
{
    width: var(--navButtonSize);
    left: 100%;
}
nav a:nth-child(5).active:hover~.animation
{
    opacity: 0;
}

/* ----------------------------Page---------------------------- */

/* -------Feuille de style pour la page------- */

.page {
    position: relative;
    z-index: -1;
}

ion-icon {
    color: var(--text);
    font-size: 30px;
}

.logo-text {
    color: var(--text);
    padding-left: 450px;
    height: 450px;
    width: 1000px;
}

.quizz {
    float: left;
    padding-top: 50px;
    padding-left: 0px;
    height: 350px;
    width: 800px;
}

.menu-text {    
    padding-top: 30px;
    color: var(--text);
    font-size: 50px;
    padding-left: 900px;
    text-align: justify;
}

.tuto { 
    padding-top: 50px;
    color: var(--text);
    font-size: 50px;
    padding-left: 50px;
}







/*slider switch css */
.theme-switch-wrapper {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    
    em {
      margin-left: 10px;
      font-size: 1rem;
    }
  }
  .theme-switch {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 34px;
    position: relative;
    width: 60px;
  }
  
  .theme-switch input {
    display:none;
  }
  
  .slider {
    background-color: #ccc;
    bottom: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    transition: .4s;
  }
  
  .slider:before {
    background-color: #fff;
    bottom: 4px;
    content: "";
    height: 26px;
    left: 4px;
    position: absolute;
    transition: .4s;
    width: 26px;
  }
  
  input:checked + .slider {
    background-color: #66bb6a;
  }
  
  input:checked + .slider:before {
    transform: translateX(26px);
  }
  
  .slider.round {
    border-radius: 34px;
  }
  
  .slider.round:before {
    border-radius: 50%;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<!-------Paramètres------->

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>E-sciences</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/menu-style.css">
    <script src="js/script.js"></script>
    <link rel="icon" type="images/png" href="image/logo.jpg">
    <link href="https://fonts.cdnfonts.com/css/huglove" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  
<style>
@import url('https://fonts.cdnfonts.com/css/huglove');
</style>


<!-------menu------->

  <body>
    <div class="cache"></div>
    <nav>
      <a class='list active' href="menu.html"><ion-icon name="home"></ion-icon> • Accueil</a>
      <a class='list' href="quizz1.html"><ion-icon name="game-controller"></ion-icon> • Quizz</a>
      <a class='list' href="quizz2.html"><ion-icon name="newspaper"></ion-icon> • Carnet de bord</a>
      <a class='list' href="#"><ion-icon name="people"></ion-icon> • Avis</a>
      <div class="animation start-home"></div>
      <div class="indicator"></div>
      <div class="theme-switch-wrapper">
          <label class="theme-switch" for="checkbox">
      <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" />
      <div class="slider round"></div></label>
    </div> 
    </nav>
    

<script type="module" src="https://unpkg.com/ionicons@5.5.2/dist/ionicons/ionicons.esm.js"></script>
<script nomodule src="https://unpkg.com/ionicons@5.5.2/dist/ionicons/ionicons.js"></script>

<!-------Page------->
    <div class="page">
        <img class="logo-text" src="image/logo_text.png" draggable="false">
        <img class="quizz" src="image/quizz.jpg" draggable="false">
        <p class="menu-text">• Avec Rythmique essayez nos quizz musicaux,<br>‎ ‎ ‎ testez vos connaissances et amusez vous !</p>
        <p class="menu-text">• Rythmique c'est gratuit et vos donnees <br>‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ sont completement securisees !</p>
        <p class="tuto">Tutoriel :<br><br>Dans la barre de navigation, cliquez sur le Quizz 1 ou 2. Ensuite, dans le Quizz, repondez aux questions et cliquez sur valider pour voir les reponses et passe a la suite.</p>

    </div>
    
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You are trying to use an element with id 'image-track' but you do not have it on the page.

Comment: this is normal, this is for anotherthing in the website. But even without it, this is still not working

Answer (score 0):

You are not setting the correct attribute value, it needs to be `theme-dark`. Update your `switchTheme(e)` function like so:

```js
/*verification question 4*/
    // if (document.getElementById("quest4").checked === true) {
    //  var preference = "Led Zeppelin";
    // }

    /*verification question 5*/
    // if (document.getElementById("quest5").checked === true) {
    //  var preference = "Au grunge";
    // }

const toggleSwitch = document.querySelector('.theme-switch input[type="checkbox"]');

function switchTheme(e) {
    if (e.target.checked) {
        document.documentElement.setAttribute('data-theme', 'theme-dark'); //< Change this
        localStorage.setItem('theme', 'theme-dark');//< Change this
    }
    else { 
        document.documentElement.setAttribute('data-theme', 'light');
        localStorage.setItem('theme', 'light');
    }    
}
```

Here is your full code snippet with the problematic JavaScript removed. As you can see the theme now toggles. Take your time and debug the rest of your JavaScript one piece at a time.

```js
/*<!-------Script du menu------->*/
/*theme switcher*/
const toggleSwitch = document.querySelector('.theme-switch input[type="checkbox"]');

function switchTheme(e) {
    if (e.target.checked) {
        document.documentElement.setAttribute('data-theme', 'theme-dark');
        localStorage.setItem('theme', 'theme-dark');
    }
    else {        document.documentElement.setAttribute('data-theme', 'light');
          localStorage.setItem('theme', 'light');
    }    
}

toggleSwitch.addEventListener('change', switchTheme, false);
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Mooli&display=swap');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Oswald:wght@500&display=swap');
/* -------Variables------- */

:root {
    --navButtonSize: 25%;
    --text: #020401;
    --background: #f1f8ef;
    --primary: #94d283;
    --secondary: #d5edce;
    --accent: #58b040;
}

[data-theme="theme-dark"] {
    --navButtonSize: 25%;
    --text: #f1f8ef;
    --background: #020401;
    --primary: #94d283;
    --secondary: #0d1a09;
    --accent: #b6e0aa;
}

/* -------Cacher la barre de scroll------- */

body 
{
  -ms-overflow-style: none; /* Pour Internet Explorer, Edge */
  scrollbar-width: none; /* Pour Firefox */
  overflow-y: scroll; 
}

body::-webkit-scrollbar 
{
  display: none; /* Pour Chrome, Safari, and Opera */
}

/* -------Fond/Police------- */

body 
{
    font-family: 'Mooli', sans-serif;
    background: var(--background);
}

/* ----------------------------Menu---------------------------- */

/* -------Barre du menu------- */

nav
{
    position: fixed;
    margin: 0px auto 0;
    margin-left: 0px;
    top: 5px;
    width: 98.5%;
    height: 50px;
    background: var(--secondary);
    border-radius: 8px;
    font-size: 0;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 3px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.1);
}

/* -------Le texte des boutons du menu------- */

nav a
{
    font-size: 30px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: var(--text);
    font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
    text-decoration: none;
    line-height: 50px;
    width: 80px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
}

/* -------Barre de survole de bouton------- */

nav .animation
{
    position: absolute;
    height: 10%;
    bottom: 0;
    z-index: 0;
    background: var(--primary);
    border-radius: 8px;
    transition: all .5s ease 0s;
    opacity: 0;
}

/* -------Indicateur de la page------- */

.indicator
{
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 0;
    background: var(--primary);
    border-radius: 8px;
    transition: all .5s ease 0s;
}

/* -------Cache le surplus (le texte qui monte) derrière le menu------- */

.cache
{
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 55px;
    background: var(--background);
    z-index: 0;
}

/* -------Les enfants de la barre de survole, de l'indicateur et des boutons du menu------- */

nav a:nth-child(1)
{
    width: var(--navButtonSize);
}
nav a:nth-child(1):hover~.animation
{
    width: var(--navButtonSize);
    left: 0%;
    opacity: 1;
}
nav a:nth-child(1).active~.indicator
{
    width: var(--navButtonSize);
    left: 0%;
}
nav a:nth-child(1).active:hover~.animation
{
    opacity: 0;
}

nav a:nth-child(2)
{
    width: var(--navButtonSize);
}
nav a:nth-child(2):hover~.animation
{
    width: var(--navButtonSize);
    left: 25%;
    opacity: 1;
}
nav a:nth-child(2).active~.indicator
{
    width: var(--navButtonSize);
    left: 25%;
}
nav a:nth-child(2).active:hover~.animation
{
    opacity: 0;
}

nav a:nth-child(3)
{
    width: var(--navButtonSize);
}
nav a:nth-child(3):hover~.animation
{
    width: var(--navButtonSize);
    left: 50%;
    opacity: 1;
}
nav a:nth-child(3).active~.indicator
{
    width: var(--navButtonSize);
    left: 50%;
}
nav a:nth-child(3).active:hover~.animation
{
    opacity: 0;
}

nav a:nth-child(4)
{
    width: var(--navButtonSize);
}
nav a:nth-child(4):hover~.animation
{
    width: var(--navButtonSize);
    left: 75%;
    opacity: 1;
}
nav a:nth-child(4).active~.indicator
{
    width: var(--navButtonSize);
    left: 75%;
}
nav a:nth-child(4).active:hover~.animation
{
    opacity: 0;
}

nav a:nth-child(5)
{
    width: var(--navButtonSize);
}
nav a:nth-child(5):hover~.animation
{
    width: var(--navButtonSize);
    left: 100%;
    opacity: 1;
}
nav a:nth-child(5).active~.indicator
{
    width: var(--navButtonSize);
    left: 100%;
}
nav a:nth-child(5).active:hover~.animation
{
    opacity: 0;
}

/* ----------------------------Page---------------------------- */

/* -------Feuille de style pour la page------- */

.page {
    position: relative;
    z-index: -1;
}

ion-icon {
    color: var(--text);
    font-size: 30px;
}

.logo-text {
    color: var(--text);
    padding-left: 450px;
    height: 450px;
    width: 1000px;
}

.quizz {
    float: left;
    padding-top: 50px;
    padding-left: 0px;
    height: 350px;
    width: 800px;
}

.menu-text {    
    padding-top: 30px;
    color: var(--text);
    font-size: 50px;
    padding-left: 900px;
    text-align: justify;
}

.tuto { 
    padding-top: 50px;
    color: var(--text);
    font-size: 50px;
    padding-left: 50px;
}







/*slider switch css */
.theme-switch-wrapper {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    
    em {
      margin-left: 10px;
      font-size: 1rem;
    }
  }
  .theme-switch {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 34px;
    position: relative;
    width: 60px;
  }
  
  .theme-switch input {
    display:none;
  }
  
  .slider {
    background-color: #ccc;
    bottom: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    transition: .4s;
  }
  
  .slider:before {
    background-color: #fff;
    bottom: 4px;
    content: "";
    height: 26px;
    left: 4px;
    position: absolute;
    transition: .4s;
    width: 26px;
  }
  
  input:checked + .slider {
    background-color: #66bb6a;
  }
  
  input:checked + .slider:before {
    transform: translateX(26px);
  }
  
  .slider.round {
    border-radius: 34px;
  }
  
  .slider.round:before {
    border-radius: 50%;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<!-------Paramètres------->

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>E-sciences</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/menu-style.css">
    <script src="js/script.js"></script>
    <link rel="icon" type="images/png" href="image/logo.jpg">
    <link href="https://fonts.cdnfonts.com/css/huglove" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  
<style>
@import url('https://fonts.cdnfonts.com/css/huglove');
</style>


<!-------menu------->

  <body>
    <div class="cache"></div>
    <nav>
      <a class='list active' href="menu.html"><ion-icon name="home"></ion-icon> • Accueil</a>
      <a class='list' href="quizz1.html"><ion-icon name="game-controller"></ion-icon> • Quizz</a>
      <a class='list' href="quizz2.html"><ion-icon name="newspaper"></ion-icon> • Carnet de bord</a>
      <a class='list' href="#"><ion-icon name="people"></ion-icon> • Avis</a>
      <div class="animation start-home"></div>
      <div class="indicator"></div>
      <div class="theme-switch-wrapper">
          <label class="theme-switch" for="checkbox">
      <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" />
      <div class="slider round"></div></label>
    </div> 
    </nav>
    

<script type="module" src="https://unpkg.com/ionicons@5.5.2/dist/ionicons/ionicons.esm.js"></script>
<script nomodule src="https://unpkg.com/ionicons@5.5.2/dist/ionicons/ionicons.js"></script>

<!-------Page------->
    <div class="page">
        <img class="logo-text" src="image/logo_text.png" draggable="false">
        <img class="quizz" src="image/quizz.jpg" draggable="false">
        <p class="menu-text">• Avec Rythmique essayez nos quizz musicaux,<br>‎ ‎ ‎ testez vos connaissances et amusez vous !</p>
        <p class="menu-text">• Rythmique c'est gratuit et vos donnees <br>‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ sont completement securisees !</p>
        <p class="tuto">Tutoriel :<br><br>Dans la barre de navigation, cliquez sur le Quizz 1 ou 2. Ensuite, dans le Quizz, repondez aux questions et cliquez sur valider pour voir les reponses et passe a la suite.</p>

    </div>
    
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: not working ;(
Nothing change

Comment: So I just checked your code locally. The answer I provided is correct. Most of your JavaScript is not working and therefore your `const toggleSwitch = document.querySelector('.theme-switch input[type="checkbox"]');` is never actually reached. You need to debug your code extensively. I have commented out the two pieces of JavaScript that were blocking your `switchTheme` function in my answer to get you started.

Comment: I have added your code snippet without all of the problematic JavaScript so you can see it working.

Comment: Not working for me, I copied everything, but the theme switcher doesn't work. Maybe beacause I'm using a multiple page website with different forlders ?
https://imgur.com/a/XGE50kM

Comment: Can you see it working in the snippet above? Did you remove all the problematic JavaScript and only leave in your `switchTheme` function?

Comment: yes, maybe there is a problem with the fact that my js file is inside an other folder ?

Comment: You need to place your `<script src="js/script.js"></script>` just before the closing `</body>` tag. Not at the top in your `<head>`. If you want to keep it in the head you would need to use `<script src="js/script.js" defer></script>` so that execution is deferred until your html had been parsed.

Comment: nothing change, still not working sadly, I out of ideas